# Yakiniku (焼き肉 or 焼肉)

Tags: kanji, food

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference for compounds with/without okurigana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6242/is-there-any-difference-for-compounds-with-without-okurigana)

I was reading the wikipedia article about [yakiniku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakiniku).
I noticed that in the title they use: (`焼き肉` or `焼肉`).

The wikipedia article for [焼](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%84%BC) says it's readings are:

- On: `しょう` (shō)
- Kun: `やく` (yaku), `やき` (yaki)

I would like to know why someone would write it as `焼き肉` instead of `焼肉`.

Comment: I don't think anyone would read it as `しょうにく`.

Comment: @istrasci: Why would you write it `焼き肉` instead of `焼肉`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy answer is that it's six in one, half a dozen in the other.

The longer answer is that having the `き` there makes it clear that you're supposed to use the kun-yomi for it. See [the previous question "What's with this “On reading”/“Kun reading” thing? Is it important to learn both as a beginner?"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6196/921) and its answers for a good discussion on on- and kun-yomi.

Comment: I didn't find info regarding reading as kun-yomi because of the `き` in that question :(

Comment: @Macarse: Yeah, it was more about general usage for the on- and kun-yomi, but snailplane's link is actually closer to what you were asking specifically :)

Comment: I think you mean *six **of** one, half a dozen **of** the other*. (-:

Comment: @hippietrai Do I? Isn't it like "six eggs in one basket, half a dozen in the other"? @-@

Comment: @silvermaple: I did some research at the time and the "of" version goes back at least two hundred years to 1807, while the "in" version is a new one I hadn't heard before but only came into existence in the 21st century.

Comment: @hippietrail: Oh wow, that's pretty interesting, I've always heard the "in" version...You learn something new every day!